# A question concerning Past Perfect Tense

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, past-perfect, past-participles

> I met him in London in 1996. I had seen him last five years before.

This is an example given for Present Perfect Tense in my grammar book. Does the sentence mean the last time the speaker had met the person was 5 years ago (1991) before they met again in London in 1996?

Comment: It's poorly written.

Comment: Agreed. It should be *... had last seen him five years earlier*, although the first part of that is arguably personal preference. The "before" screams for a "that". But why is this two sentences? A run-on would actually fit...

Comment: FWIW, I don't agree it is poorly written. It is instead slightly old fashioned language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it means 1991. But that has nothing to do with past perfect, it would be the same with simple past:

> I saw him last five years before.

The word "before" needs a time to refer to, and the only possible reference in this context is "1996". It's short for "before then".

To refer to a time relative to the current date you would use "ago" rather than "before".

Comment: "The Past Perfect describes an action completed before a certain moment in the past" the example sentence is given for this statement. Does It mean to say that the past perfect tense is used to describe an action happened earlier to a certain action in the past?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. But since seeing someone is a short-term action, not a continuous action that's completed, we don't need to use it for this.